# how to clear process from memroy when it is killed

Tags: android, memory-management

how to clear process from memory when it is killed, i do not care the process is empty or do nothing. just want to clear it from memory.

OR

After read a 1M file once, it will be read from memory/cache when read it twice.
the question is can it be clear from memory or cache after once read?

thanks

Comment: you want to kill the application process.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is: **you don't "clear it"**: you let android handle them. Any process will be killed if (when) there is a memory need. Regarding caches, the **garbage collector** will take care of it. Again, no need to do anything on your side (except, maybe, making sure you did not leave live references to it somewhere).

I am quoting below part of [**Dianne Hackborn's** post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html) in the android blog:

> When does an application "stop"?
>
> A common misunderstanding about
>   Android multitasking is the difference
>   between a process and an application.
>   In Android these are not tightly
>   coupled entities: applications may
>   seem present to the user without an
>   actual process currently running the
>   app; multiple applications may share
>   processes, or one application may make
>   use of multiple processes depending on
>   its needs; the process(es) of an
>   application may be kept around by
>   Android even when that application is
>   not actively doing something.
>
> The fact that you can see an
>   application's process "running" does
>   not mean the application is running or
>   doing anything. It may simply be there
>   because Android needed it at some
>   point, and has decided that it would
>   be best to keep it around in case it
>   needs it again. Likewise, you may
>   leave an application for a little bit
>   and return to it from where you left
>   off, and during that time Android may
>   have needed to get rid of the process
>   for other things.
>
> A key to how Android handles
>   applications in this way is that
>   processes don't shut down cleanly.
>   When the user leaves an application,
>   its process is kept around in the
>   background, allowing it to continue
>   working (for example downloading web
>   pages) if needed, and come immediately
>   to the foreground if the user returns
>   to it. If a device never runs out of
>   memory, then Android will keep all of
>   these processes around, truly leaving
>   all applications "running" all of the
>   time.
>
> Of course, there is a limited amount
>   of memory, and to accommodate this
>   Android must decide when to get rid of
>   processes that are not needed. This
>   leads to Android's process lifecycle,
>   the rules it uses to decide how
>   important each process is and thus the
>   next one that should be dropped. These
>   rules are based on both how important
>   a process is for the user's current
>   experience, as well as how long it has
>   been since the process was last needed
>   by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for killing the process, this might help,

```
 int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
     android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

    r.gc();
    System.gc();
```